# CString 'Trim' : is not a member, why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, compiler-errors, visual-c++-2010-express

I have simple app that I try to compile with VC express and using the:
Microsoft platform SDK for Windows server 2003 that contains MFC and ATL.
Now I have this simple code :

```
CString strValue("test");
CString s = strValue.Trim();
LPCTSTR lpStr = (LPCTSTR)strValue.Trim()
```

that give me a compilation error : 
c:\dev\test.cpp(463) : error C2039: 'Trim' : is not a member of 'CString'
 c:\program files\microsoft platform sdk for windows server 2003 r2\include\mfc\afx.h(369) : see declaration of 'CString'

do I have a problem with the platform SDK and vc express?

Answer (score 5):

Visual C++ Express Edition don't has built in support for ATL and MFC (`CString` is an MFC class, implemented as the shared MFC/ATL `CStringT` class: [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea(VS.80).aspx)).

If you really can't afford the Standard Edition, you can rely on this howto to add ATL and MFC support by installing the DDK: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/MFCinVisualStudioExpress.aspx

Comment: Thanks , but Microsoft doesn't have this version to download any more 
where can i find it?

Comment: You can download the **trial** of Visual Studio 2010 Professional or Ultimate: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/download

Comment: To download current versions of WDK you have to register on https://connect.microsoft.com and enroll the Windows Driver Kit program (it is free).

Comment: does the new ddk has mfc/atl?

Answer (score 2):

You could try TrimLeft(), TrimRight() functions of CString instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using the MFC from the "Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows Server 2003 R2" seems to install an earlier version of MFC where CString doesn't have the Trim() function yet. Use TrimLeft() and TrimRight() in combination instead.

This link to the Visual C++ 6 version of CString documentation shows that the method doesn't exist there, yet:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa315043%28v=vs.60%29.aspx